# Material UI: Multiline Textfield does not expand with new rows

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following basic Textfield:

```
<TextField multiline fullWidth id="standard-textarea" label="Method" value={mealmethod} name="mealmethod" onChange={e => setMethod(e.currentTarget.value)} minRows={2} maxRows={4} variant="outlined" />
```

If I enter anything over 2 rows of text the textarea does not grow/expand with the new lines. If I remove the minRows and maxRows - this makes no difference.

How do I make this multiline expand with each new row of text?

Comment: I tried your code and it seems work for me. Can you provide more code snippets or information about this question, maybe other causes?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [Textarea Autosize](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-textarea-autosize/) in order to automatically adjust the textarea. Here is an example.

```
<TextareaAutosize
  id="standard-textarea" 
  defaultValue={mealmethod}
  placeholder="Empty"
/>
```